# Proximity Monitoring always returns false

Tags: swift

I'm trying to detect `UIDevice.current.proximityState` but it always returns `false`, despite setting `UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled` to true and it printing out as true when I check it. Any ideas?

Using this code on an iPhone X and 6S with same results.

Have the following code running on a timer

```
UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
print("enabled: \(UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled)") // prints true
print("state: \(UIDevice.current.proximityState)") // always prints false, even when sensor is covered.
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: whoever downvoted this question please explain. seems simple enough.

Comment: two more down votes, thanks, maybe a comment to explain instead? would that be too helpful?

Comment: Your title is misleading. Actually your proximity state seems to always return false...

Answer (score 1):

Do you check the state on the main thread?

```
    var myTimer: Timer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@objc func runTimedCode() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
        print("enabled: \(UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled)") // prints true
        print("state: \(UIDevice.current.proximityState)")
    }
}
```

And it works on iPhone X

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I'm still getting false returned though which is so strange.

Comment: Strangest thing is that in a new project, this code works, but when I put it in my existing project, it always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug with the xcode beta or iOS beta.

The exact same code sometimes registers and sometimes not. Very confusing.

I'll update this answer if I figure anything out but for now, consider this a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a listener to proximity did change event. It works for me

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  // other setup
  UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  // other setup
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notifyProximityChange), name: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func notifyProximityChange() {
    if UIDevice.current.proximityState {
        print("And it's closed to your face")
    } else {
        print("not anymore")
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer at the end of the life cycle

[image]